# C++ - Creating non-abstract objects from abstract objects

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I've got this base class

```
class Object {
 ...
 public:
  virtual void move() = 0;
  virtual void move(string) = 0;
  virtual void powerOn() = 0;
  virtual void powerOff() = 0;
  virtual void speak() = 0; 
};
```

This will be the base class for different classes

```
class Electronics : public Object {
 ...
 public:
  virtual void powerOn();
  virtual void powerOff();
};

void Electronics::powerOn() { ... }
void Electronics::powerOff() { ... }

class Phone : public Electronics {
 ...
 public:
};
```

Now, if I want to create an object Phone, that uses teh powerOn() and powerOff() methods. I don't need the other three methods.

```
Object *obj = new Phone;
```

But this would probably give me an error saying

```
undefined reference to move()
undefined reference to move(string)
undefined reference to speak()
```

My question is, how can I avoid this error. I don't need these functions for Phone, but it requires me to do something with them. How can I ge past this error?

Thanks

Comment: you can remove those functions from Object and use them in lower subclasses where you really need them

Comment: I need to later do something like: Object *phone = new Phone. And later, when I call phone->powerOn() it'll say that there's no powerOn() method in class Object

Answer (score 0):

You can provide empty implementation of those virtual methods in either `Electronics` or `Object` (make the methods non abstract). Or if both need to be this way you need to re-implement them in `Phone`. You cannot however "hide" them in `Phone` unless you remove them from its base(s).

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by "empty implementation"

Comment: @thisisalongdisplayname As TommyA mentioned, empty implementation is a fucntion/method with empty body, e.g. foo() { }

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already you can create an empty implementations of them in the `Electronics` class, in other words overwrite the method in this class, and simply let it have an empty body. (See example here: http://ideone.com/jM2hX7)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Object {
 public:
  virtual void move() = 0;
  virtual void move(string) = 0;
  virtual void powerOn() = 0;
  virtual void powerOff() = 0;
  virtual void speak() = 0; 
};

class Electronics : public Object {
 public:
  virtual void move() override {}
  virtual void move(string) override {}
  virtual void powerOn() override {cout << "powerOn" << endl;}
  virtual void powerOff() override {cout << "powerOff" << endl;}
  virtual void speak() override {} 
};

class Phone : public Electronics {
  virtual void powerOn() override {cout << "phone:powerOn" << endl;}
  virtual void powerOff() override {cout << "phone:powerOff" << endl;}
};

int main() {
    Object* phone = new Phone;

    phone->move();
    phone->powerOn();
    phone->powerOff();
    phone->speak();     

    delete phone;
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
phone:powerOn
phone:powerOff
```

More importantly though you might want to rethink your class design, is it really necessary to have pure virtual methods such as `powerOn`, `powerOff`, `speak`, ... in your class: `Object`. Object sounds really general, and these functions, sounds more specific. `Object` should ideally only consist of functions that makes sense for all classes inheriting from it.

These functions might make more sense in the `Electronics` class, even though even that, seems a bit too general.

If it really is required to have these objects in the `Object` class, then I would personally rename it to something more saying.

Comment: Yes, but when I do: Object *phone = new Phone, and at some later point call phone>powerOn(), it'll say that Object class has no method called powerOn()

Comment: @thisisalongdisplayname why would it say that, if you have implemented the `powerOn` method, as you have in the `Electronics` class?

Comment: Since Phone is an Object type, when I call pwerOn(), it'll look for powerOn() in the Object class. Is that not right?

Comment: @thisisalongdisplayname in that case I would definitely change the name of your class `Object` to something more relevant to the child classes using it. I'm not a fan of naming classes `Object` it might make sense in a Java like language where everything is ultimately inheriting from such a class, but in C++ I would choose a more specific naming.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. This isn' my actual code. I'm working on a schoo assignment so I can't pos the actual code here. This is just a representation of what's going on in my code

Comment: Also, I just tried to compile your code. It says the override does not name a type. Am I doign something wrong?

Comment: @thisisalongdisplayname it appears you are using an older compiler, one that does not support C++11, just remove the `override` specifier.